# Does $\sin(x)=y$ have a solution in $\mathbb{Q}$ beside $x=y=0$

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers

Is there a way to show, that the only solution of 
$$\sin(x)=y$$ 
is $x=y=0$ with $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$.

I am seaching a way to prove it with the things you learn in linear algebra and analysis 1+2 (with the knowledge of a second semester student).

Comment: This is at least as hard as proving that $\pi$ is irrational, so I doubt you'll get an answer at the level you want.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry for the previous spam. I shall prove for $\cos$, cosine of any rational numbers except for 0 cannot get rational numbers.

By using polynomial argument, we shall only have to prove for integers.

Suppose that $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $\cos(m)\in\mathbb{Q}$.

For any fixed prime number $p>m$, consider polynomial $x\in(0,m)$
$$f(x) = \frac{(x-m)^{2p}(m^2-(x-m)^2)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}$$

And 
$$F(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{2p-1} (-1)^{n+1}f^{2n}(x)$$
Which satisfies
$$(F'(x)\sin(x)-F(x)\cos(x))' = F''(x)\sin(x) +F(x)\sin(x) = f(x)\sin(x)$$
since the other terms cancelled.
$$\int_0^mf(x)\sin(x)dx = F'(m)\sin(m)-F(m)\cos(m)+F(0)$$
Consider $f$ is a polynomial of $(x-m)^2$, thus $F'(m) = 0$, and we can see that 
$$f(m-x) = x^{2p}(m^2-x^2)^{p-1}/(p-1)!$$
By computing, $p|f^{(l)}(m)$ for every $l$. That means $F(m)$ is a multiple of $p$ by definition of $F$, say $pM$.

If $\cos(m) = s/t$, then 
$$t\int_0^m f(x)\sin(x)dx = -spM+tN$$
is an integer,
While
$$f\le \frac{m^{4p-2}}{(p-1)!} $$
thus
$$t\int_0^mf(x)\sin(x)dx\le t\frac{m^{4p-2}}{(p-1)!}\cdot m <1 $$
when $p$ is large enough. Contradiction of it is an integer.

As a result of this, $\sin$ should also satisfy this.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis To prove this you might need to use function $f(x) = \frac{x^p(m-x)^{2p}(2m-x)^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}$ and $F(x) = f(x)-f^{(2)}(x) + f^{(4)}(x) -\dots +f^{(4p-2)}(x)$. And give a contradiction for $\int_0^m f(x)\cos(x)$.

Comment: Actually, it is not a polynomial either, think $\sin 2\theta$. The cosine function is better behaved!

Comment: @AndréNicolas, oh,yes, it is for $\cos$. I will modify the proof for $\cos$

Comment: @Yimin: This very closely resembles Niven’s proof of the irrationality of $ \pi $.

Comment: @HaskellCurry  Yes, I think so, I have read his proof before, and I spent some time to re-prove this and wrote down.

Comment: @HaskellCurry I was going to say the exact same thing.

Comment: Sorry I thought a longer time about it but I only can deduce from $\cos$ fulfilling this property to $\sin$ must be quadratic irrational or better behaved could you help me a bit ?

Answer (score 8):

One can hit it with a really heavy-duty theorem, the [Lindemann-Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) theorem. It is a consequence of this that if $x$ is non-zero algebraic, then $\sin x$ is transcendental.

Ivan Niven, in his book Rational and Irrational numbers, has a nice proof, "elementary" but not entirely simple, of the fact that the sine of a non-zero rational is irrational. That proof does not make any real use of linear algebra.

Comment: I know that theorem, but this problem was hidden in a linear algebra 2 exam due to a typo, so i wanted to know if it had been possible to solve it without "cheating"